# Execute external process from java. Got the output after the process terminated, but need it before termination

Tags: java, process, live, execution

Why I get the output of the process after the process has terminated? I need to get the process output "live", while the process is running and not after the process has terminated. I would like to run a process like a jboss, which is logging on the standard output, so I need that information in time, and not after the process has terminated. Thank you for answers.

Here is my code:

```
        try {
        process = processBuilder.start();
        processOutput = process.getOutputStream();
        processInput = process.getInputStream();
        processReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                processInput));
        processWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                processOutput));

        while ((line = processReader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
          }
        processReader.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Extension:

So I would like to run an external program from an eclipse plug-in with a button. When I click to the button, the program start and the output of the external program will go back to the console. When I click to the stop, the program stops. So here is how I make the instance of the process builder. And I made an example class to test the process builder without start the whole plugin project in every modification.

Here is my process builder instance which is implements the Runnable:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    List<String> command = new ArrayList<String>();
    command.add(serverPath);
    command.add(String.valueOf(count));
    command.add(filePath);
    processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
    processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);

    try {
        process = processBuilder.start();
        processOutput = process.getOutputStream();
        processInput = process.getInputStream();
        processReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                processInput));
        processWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                processOutput));

        System.out.println(process.waitFor());
        while ((line = processReader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);

        }
        processReader.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

The parameters are come in the constructor. And here is the instantiation:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
```

{

```
 SimulationProcess smp = new SimulationProcess(count, "file",
            "program_name");
    smp.run();
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few things you can try to resolve your issue:

a) Make a test program and run it with your above code to ensure you can read it properly. For example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  for(;;) {
    try {
      Thread.sleep(5000);
      System.out.println("Test output");
    } catch(InterruptedException e) {
      // Ignore
    }

  }
}
```

b) Make sure you are handling the process' error stream - the process can lock up if you do not handle the error stream. Look at [this site](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html) for a tutorial on the things to avoid while using Java's ProcessBuilder or Runtime.exec() - it includes an implementation of a StreamGobbler that will throw away all data on a stream you don't care about.

c) Try using `System.out.flush()` - it may be that your output is being buffered.

EDIT: Thanks for the update. Your problem is here:

```
System.out.println(process.waitFor()); // Waits for the process to exit.
while ((line = processReader.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

If you remove the waitFor() it will keep printing until the stream closes. The stream should only close if the process dies. You should put the `waitFor()` after the loop?

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer. Now I try it with a simple program, nothing around just this code. I do it with the   processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true); so I haven't got to handle the error stream. And I try to use the Syso.flush, but it does not work. I make sure that code is work, because the process is started, and when I stop it manually, or causing an event which terminate the process, I got the output to my console without error.

Comment: So, even with a very simple program like the one I have above it still outputs after it exits? How are you executing the program? Can you update your question with how you set up your `ProcessBuilder` instance?

Comment: I extended my question as you requested. Sorry for late answer, but I was away for a week.

Comment: I've edited my answer. Your code is doing as you are asking! You're telling it to `waitFor()` the process to exit before you print anything.

Comment: The System.out.flush() before the while-loop did it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your output does not contain a newline character, that way your while-loop won't do anything until the process is finished.

Try it using another read method which does not wait for a newline-character, for example:

```
char[] cbuf = new char[10];
while(processReader.read(cbuf) != -1)
{
  System.out.print(cbuf);
}
```

Comment: I checked your answer, but it does not working yet. I try to increase the size of cbuf, but that way was not working also. Anyway, thank you for your answer.